# Check if $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x^{1/2}}=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Could anyone tell me which of the following is/are true?

> 1. $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x^{1/2}}=0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x}=\infty$
> 2. $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x^{1/2}}=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x}=0$
> 3. $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x^{1/2}}=0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x}=0$
> 4. $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x^{1/2}}=0$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log x\over x}$ does not exists.

For I know $\lim_{x\to\infty}{1\over x}$  exist and so is for $1\over x^{1/2}$.

Comment: Does this question assume $\log$ is the natural logarithm, or $\log_{10}$? (Not really relevant to the answer, but should be included)

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi: Does it matter when $x\to \infty$ is such a large  number?

Comment: @Inceptio: No, but if anyone's going to prove it with L'hospital's rule, then it's important to know what you're taking the derivative of, even if it doesn't really matter for the end result.

Comment: Number $(3)$ is true.

Comment: Both $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}{1\over x}$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}{1\over x^{1/2}}$  **exist** and both are $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3$ is correct as $\log x$ grows slower than any $x^n$. So $x^{-1}$ and $x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ will manage to pull it down to $0$. And $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}{1\over x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}{1\over \sqrt{x}}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to generalize the function, I'll write it as:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^n}$$
For $n>0$. Using L'Hôpital's rule gives:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^n}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{nx^{n-1}}\\=\frac{1}{n}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^n}\\=0$$

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: @kimchi lover As I explained, the only restriction to $n$ is that it's nonzero. When $n=0$, the limit diverges.

Comment: And for $n=-1$, too?  That's nonzero.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about negative $n$. The limit converges only for $n>0$. I'll edit my answer.